# Regex - match on string that contains only digits and starts with a specific digit

Tags: java, regex

In my case, the starting digit should be nine. I've tried `^9[0-9]`, but it's not working.

Example input:
- 90123661337080429320550294 (valid)
- 80123661337080429320550294 (invalid)
- 90123661337080429320550DCB (invalid)

Comment: Please post example input strings and expected results.

Comment: May be your looking for this: `^9[0-9]+$` and your input should be a string!

Comment: `/^9\d*$/` maybe can solve your problem

Comment: Definitely consider `\d` instead of `[0-9]`; it has a clearer meaning ("any digit" versus "any character between 0 and 9").

Comment: @DwB Will do, thank you!

Comment: @DwB offtopic, but isn't [0-9] better because \d can match more than 10 characters?

Comment: No.  `\d` matches exactly one digit.  A digit is defined as any character between 0 and 9 inclusive.

Comment: @DwB what I meant to say is that it can match characters other than [0-9] that's why it is dangerous to use

Comment: There are no digits other than 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.  "\d" matches exactly one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `$` at the end to enforce no stray characters at the end, and `*` to allow repetition:

`^9[0-9]*$`